Unable to run oracle-client docker container
I am trying to run the container build from the image build with node 14 which has the following Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libaio1 \
        build-essential \
        unzip \
        curl \
        python \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip .
COPY instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip .

RUN mkdir -p /opt/oracle \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y -qq nodejs \
    && unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && mv /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1 /opt/oracle/instantclient \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so \
    && rm -rf instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip \
    && rm -rf instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient
ENV OCI_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient
ENV OCI_LIB_DIR=/opt/oracle/instantclient
ENV OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include

RUN echo '/opt/oracle/instantclient/' | tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle_instant_client.conf \
    && ldconfig

RUN apt-get -y -qq install git \
    && npm install -g pm2

EXPOSE 17001 8000

I am able to successfully build the image using the command docker build -t oracle-client-image ., but when I try to run the container using the command Run docker run -d -p 17001:17001 -p 8000:8000 -name oracle-client-container oracle-client-image the container just exits out. It doedn't even throw any error when I do docker logs -f oracle-client-container. Is there anything wrong with the Dockerfile?

You don't seem to have included a CMD in the Dockerfile.  What should the main container process be?

(i) 12.1 is old. (ii) node-oracledb doesn't need the sdk (iii) Never set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client, and don't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH since you run ldconfig. Node-oracledb doesn't use OCI_LIB_DIR or OCI_INCLUDE_DIR (iv) node-oracledb 6.0 doesn't need Instant Client (v) review Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python
